# Javascript how to print value from object using recursive

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an object

```
var abb = {"DATA":[{"A":"122","B":"444","C":"fff"},
                    {"A":"1223","B":"6666","C":"s"},
                    {"A":"555","B":"76666","C":"pod"},
                    {"A":"7676","B":"34345","C":""},
                    {"A":"54553","B":"2325555","C":""}]};
```

this is my code

```
var recursive_f =function(a){
        if(a.length > 0){
            console.log(a[0]);
            recursive_f(a.slice(1));
        }
    }
    recursive_f(abb.DATA);
```

my result like this
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH0Kp.png)

but I want this
[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGBYd.png)

Comment: There is nothing about your data structure that suggests the use of recursion. It is an object containing an array of objects, nothing more. There are no arbitrarily nested objects, which is where recursion would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[0]` is an object and you want all the values of the object in an array. Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) for that.

```js
var abb = {"DATA":[{"SLIP_NO":"RE2018070006","IO_DATE":"2018-07-11 00:00:00.0","REMARK":"185"},{"SLIP_NO":"RE2012060003","IO_DATE":"2012-06-06 00:00:00.0","REMARK":""},{"SLIP_NO":"RE2012060003","IO_DATE":"2012-06-06 00:00:00.0","REMARK":""},{"SLIP_NO":"RE2018030028","IO_DATE":"2018-03-14 00:00:00.0","REMARK":""},{"SLIP_NO":"RE2018030029","IO_DATE":"2018-03-14 00:00:00.0","REMARK":""}]};

var recursive_f = function(a) {
  if (a.length > 0) {
    console.log(Object.values(a[0]));
    recursive_f(a.slice(1));
  }
}
recursive_f(abb.DATA);
```

**Note** : I am assuming that you have build this function to test out something. Because for looping through an Array, you should use `Array.forEach` or a for `loop`.